# how do I fix this coding issue?

Tags: sql

```
WITH nl_sentcount
AS(
Select nl_id, count(user_id) as sent_num
from sheet1$
Where event_type='nlsent'
group by nl_id
)
```

Why the error shows as

> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 7
> Incorrect syntax near ')'.

Comment: what do you have after your cte ?

Comment: The query is incomplete: CTE (`WITH`) without main query. Try adding `select * from nl_sentcount`

Comment: Alternatively, `create view nl_sentcount as Select nl_id, count(user_id) as sent_num from sheet1$ Where event_type='nlsent' group by nl_id`, and you can SELECT from nl_sentcount  many times.

Answer (score 2):

You need a `select` statement *after* the `WITH` to do something:

```
WITH nl_sentcount AS (
      Select nl_id, count(user_id) as sent_num
      from sheet1$
      Where event_type='nlsent'
      group by nl_id
     )
select *
from nl_sentcount;
```